# Xero testing webhooks on localhost

Tags: php, webhooks, xero-api

So I am running a PHP application on localhost and I want to test an incoming web hook. Is there a recommended way to test the local development for this?

Is there an example web hook invoice-paid POST request I could just test with something like postman on my localhost?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tool like ngrok or Pagekite to expose your local server. You download and run a program on your machine and provide it the port of a network service, usually a web server.

It connects to the ngrok cloud service which accepts traffic on a public address and relays that traffic through to the ngrok process running on your machine and then on to the local address you specified.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a blog post on the topic

https://devblog.xero.com/lets-play-web-hooky-with-php-34a141dcac0a

Comment: Thanks dude. I just setup ngrok and its working like a charm. I have pointed my webhook a URL for my local app but what's the best way to send test webhook requests from xero?

Comment: You can connect to Xero's Demo company, then create a new Invoice or Contact (depending on which type of webhook event you have enabled), then watch ngrok terminal to see event data. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/getting-started/development-accounts

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngrok for test webhook in your local machine. Here is an additional detail to @sidney.maestre answer,
You only have to use Xero demo company in developer console for once,
then you can use the "Replay" button to use exact request every time in ngrok's dashboard.

Comment: Provide additional details in comment section, not as an answer